Ошибка: 'AxiosError: Network Error' при выполнении запроса с react native на сервер fastapi
Вот мой React Native код:
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
    const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('')
    const [userPass, setUserPass] = useState('')


    const handleRegister = () => {
        if (userName.trim() === '' || userEmail.trim() === '' || userPass.trim() === '') {
            Alert.alert('Уведомление', 'Пожалуйста заполните все поля');
        } else {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/register", true)
            xhr.withCredentials = true
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register', {
                userName,
                userEmail,
                userPass
            }, { withCredentials: true }).then(() => {
                navigation.navigate("SelectHobby")
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                Alert.alert("Произошла ошибка при регистрации")
            })
        }
    }

FastApi:

    async def create_database():
    async with aiosqlite.connect('users.db') as db:
        await db.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
                         id TEXT,
                         name TEXT,
                         email TEXT,
                         password TEXT
        )""")

        await db.commit()


app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    password: str


@app.post('/register')
async def get_user_data(user: User):
    async with aiosqlite.connect('users.db') as db:
        await db.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (str(uuid.uuid4()), user.username, user.email, user.password))
        await db.commit()

        data = await db.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        res = await data.fetchall()
        print(res)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(create_database())

Пробовал через CORS тоже не получалось. Мне нужно отправить данные на сервер где я занесу из в бд, но выдаётся ошибка: AxiosError: Network Error
